# How transaction works with multiple Persistence unit

Tags: java, jpa, jersey

I have a class having two persistence unit something like this

```
@Stateless
public class SearchRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "XYZ")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ABC")
    private EntityManager entityManager1;

    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void doSomething(){
        entityManager.persist(someentity);
        entityManager1.remove(someentity);
    }
}
```

I have this code and working fine can anybody please explain how the transaction is managed in this type of code. How JPA manage transaction with multiple persistence unit I am not able to guess how the transaction is working here. Any help will be apricaiated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "JPA" does do anything with "multiple persistence unit". An EntityManager handles transactional capabilities for a single persistence-unit and that is the sum total of JPA's handling. Other aspects are handled outside of JPA

Answer (score 1):

`@Transactional` binds to your default `PlatformTransactionManager`-Bean -- e.g. `entityManager`. Using `entityManager1` will presumably interact with this PersistenceContext in a non-transactional manner.

[The default behaviour of `@Transactional` can be changed using the attribute `transactionManager`.]